# Upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

Yes, not a typo. 10.04 to 16.04

If I attempt to do this am I going to lose data and software?
I have backed up my files to a portable hard drive, but what about emails and address book in evolution 2.28.3
I have copied my bookmarks to be hard drive as well.

I have downloaded 16.04 do I just install it.

What are the gotchas I need to know about?

Comment: Having all of your user data `/home` on a separate partition helps in these situation. That way you can, if you have to, wipe the OS, but leave the user data. The next step of maturity (one I am just starting), is to write a script for all system changes. That way I can do a fresh install, and re-run the scripts. Good luck with learning command line, it will make your life easier (one  you are over the first 30 days).

Comment: Maybe a candidate for askubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, even just upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 is a huge task that's not likely to work well at all. I once attempted it and apparently loads of packages failed to install/be replaced properly and I encountered a kernel panic straight at the next booting attempt.

Not many people would want to make such a huge leap between versions. Normally you'd just want to backup your data and do a clean reinstall of the newer version of the system, then put your data back.

Search on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and you will find more Q/As sharing the same advice.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading is not recommended. There are numerous reports of upgrades not being successful, data lost etc. It's always always *always* better to do a clean install. You can upgrade by all means, but don't expect it go absolutely smoothly. It's just as well you backed your data up.

The install process itself for 16.04 is very easy. In fact it's the easiest OS install I've ever done, easier and quicker than Windows 7. All GUI-based and no command lines. I don't think you'll have any issues with it.